# Working with numeric text field in material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working with material and want to have a numeric input. Using the solution they provide in the documentation isn't working:

```
<TextField inputProps={{ inputMode: 'numeric', pattern: '[0-9]*' }} />
```

It looks like a feature for future. But I wanted to know what is the best way to work around numeric input using material ui and only accept number as input. Currently I can type letter in the text field

Comment: You can use simply `type="number"`, but only Chromium-based browsers will enforce numeric input (and "e", +, -).

Comment: MUI mentioned that as in [limitations](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#limitations). Like @tromgy mentioned, you can use `type="number"` for your case. Check [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#form-props) from MUI

Comment: this works for me `inputProps={{'inputMode': 'numeric', 'aria-label': 'whatever you want'}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you could change the inputMode:'numric' to type:'number' and remove the pattern you can try the code snippet like this:

```js
<TextField inputProps={{ type: 'number'}} />
```

[image]

This will only accept number as input.

Comment: This is not working